# Save pointers of two different users in a PFObject

Tags: objective-c, ios7, parse-platform

I am trying to create an PFobject in parse called userFriendRelationships. The object is meant to store two User pointers and another field called status.  I don't want to use the relationship method in parse because I need the additional field status.  Unfortunately, I am getting the following error when I try to save the object. It works when I make an object when both User pointers belong to [PFUser currentUser], but it will crash when I set one of the objects to a different user.  The code throws the error:

Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp":

My Code is as follows:

```
PFObject *userFriendRequest = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"userFriendRequests"];
                [userFriendRequest setObject:myUserContact forKey:@"invited"];
                [userFriendRequest setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"inviter"];
                [userFriendRequest setObject:@"pending" forKey:@"status"];
                [userFriendRequest saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
                    if (succeeded) {
                        UILabel *disclosureLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 21)];
                        disclosureLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                        disclosureLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                        [disclosureLabel setText:@"Invited"];
                        [cell setAccessoryView:disclosureLabel];
                        [[self.allKnownUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@"pending" forKey:@"status"];
                        [self.tableView reloadData];

                    }
                    else {
                        //NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
                        [cell setAccessoryView:nil];

                    }

                }];
```

I have tried variations where, I first query for a PFUser myUserContact as follows:

```
PFUser *myUserContact = objects[0];
```

as well as trying:

```
PFUser *myUserContact = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"_User" objectId:@"GI7CEb2TH6"];
```

and:

```
PFUser *myUserContact = [PFUser objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:@"GI7CEb2TH6"];
```

Same error each time.  There are no ACLs or CLPs set on the userFriendRequests table.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a Cloud Code function and use the Master Key to do this.